# using threading to call the main function again?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am really trying to wrap my head around the concept of **Threading** concept in practical applications. I am using the `Threading` module in **python 3.4** and I am not sure if the logic is right for the program functionality.

Here is the gist of my code:

```
def myMain():
 """ my main function actually uses sockets to 
     send data over a network
 """
# there will be an infinite loop call it loop-1 here
while True:
        #perform encoding scheme
        #send data out... with all other exception handling


       # here is infinite loop 2 which waits for messages
       # from other devices
       while True:
             # Check for incoming messages
             callCheckFunction() ----> Should I call this on a thread?
```

the above mentioned `callCheckFunction()` will do some comparison on the received data and if the data values don't match I want to run the `myMain()` function again.

Here is the gist of the `callCheckFunction()`:

```
def callCheckFunction():
       if data == 'same':
          # some work done here and then get out
          # function and return back to listening on the socket
       else data == 'not same':
           myMain() ---------> Should I thread this one too??
```

This might be complicated but I am not sure if **Threading** is the thing I want. I did a *nasty hack* by calling the `myMain()` function the above mentioned fashioned which works great! but I assume there will definitely some limit to calling the function within the function and I want my code to be a bit *professional* not Hacky!

I have my mind set on **Threading** since I am listening to the socket in an infinite fashion when some new Data comes in **the whole `myMain()`** is called back creating kind of a hectic recursion which I want to control.

### EDIT

So I have managed to make the code a bit more modular i.e. I have split the two Infinite Loops in to two **different functions**

now `myMain` is divided into

- `task1()`
- `task2()`

and the gist is as follows:

```
def task1():
    while True:
       # encoding and sending data

       #in the end I call task2() since it the primary
       # state which decides things
       task2() ---------> still need to decide if I should thread or not

 def task2():
    while True:
          # check for incoming messages

          checker = threading.Thread(callCheckFunction, daemon=True)
          checker.start()
          checker.join()
```

Now since the `callCheckFunction()` needs the `func1()` I decided to *Thread* `func1()` in the function **Note** `func1` is actually kinda the `main()` of the code:

```
def callCheckFunction():
      else data == 'not same':
           thready = threading.Thread(func1, daemon= True)
           thready.start()
           thready.join()
```

### Results

with little understanding I do manage to get the code working. But I am not sure if this is really *hacky* or a professional way of doing things! I can ofcourse share the code via GitHub and also a Finite State Machine for the system. Also I am not sure if this code is **Thread Safe** ! But Help/Suggestions really needed